# UK PLAB visa refusal

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I recently got a visa refusal for uk visit visa. As my father is sponsoring me he encashed some of the money from his fixed deposit and transferred in to his account i provided the evidence of encashment with my visa application.

Decision

"I have refused your application for a visit visa because I am not satisfied that you meet the requirements of paragraph(s) V4.2 (a) and V4.2 (c) of Appendix V and visitors Appendix 3: Immigration rules of visitors because:

You have applied for a visa to undertake your PLAB 2 examination in the UK. Whilst you have provided evidence of your registration for this exam I must also consider your personal and financial circumstances.

You state that you have been employed as a Doctor with the xxx since June 2015, where you earn a monthly income of PKR 20,000. In support of his statement you have provided a letter of reference from the head of department. However , this document has been produced a your own request and I am not satisfied that this single letter,in isolation,supports your circumstances. If I were to accept this document then I must consider that you have only been employed in this capacity for less than 3 months prior to submission of your UK visa application.

With regards to the proposed expenditure you state that 3000 pounds is available for your visit and that your father will meet all of the costs associated with your stay. In support of this statement you have provided an affidavit from your father and his personal bank account statement. However, there are a number of recent, large cash deposits which are inconsistent with the overall transactional history of the account. I therefore consider that the balance has been inflated just prior to submission of your UK visa application.

In the absence of evidence to demonstrate the origin of these funds, I am not satisfied that these will remain available to you or that this account statement is an accurate reflection of his financial circumstances.

Given the evidence before me I am not satisfied that you have accurately presented your circumstances or intentions in wishing to enter United Kingdom. I am therefore not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry for a purpose permitted by the visitor routes or that you will leave the United Kingdom at the end of your visit. I therefore refuse your application under paragraphs V4.2 (a) and V4.2 (c) of Appendix V

Q1 : I plan to reapply in Jan 2016 , i contacted the bank from where the fixed deposits were cashed and transferred in to the account. They are ready to provide me with a encashment certificate that will state the amount withdrawn with dates. Is that evidence sufficient enough to prove the origin of the funds?

Q2 : How should my father balance his account statement after the deposits. He receives monthly pension , rents from the properties and interest from the fixed deposits.

Q3 : As i stated i will reapply in Jan 2016 by then i will be unemployed as i will quit my job next month due to my upcoming exams I will explain in my application that i resigned from my job and will attach a experience certificate given to me by the hospital. Will my unemployment and resignation from the job , raise any red flags or have a negative impact on my application which will lead to refusal?

My father would still be supporting me financially when i will reapply.

Comment: Note that [this was asked apparently identically over on Travel as well](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53440/uk-plab-general-visit-visa-refusal)

Comment: PLABs are done under the visitor rules.  This is not an Expats question! Close voting as OT.

Answer (score 2):

Q1. Probably not. The UK really wants to know the origin of the money. Not just another bit of the path of its journey into your account.

Q2. I think perhaps this question is missing the point. If you are working earning 20,000 RS per month, with some support from your father over a significant period, you should probably be able to demonstrate, rather readily, some financial stability. So carefully balanced accounts isn't what you need to show the UK. If this is indeed your situation, those account balances will show that without need for significant manipulation. Just make sure any support you receive from him is recorded through proper regular bank transactions.

Q3. Well, just referring to the letter of refusal, it appears that one of the key reasons for your refusal is that you have ***only*** worked at the hospital for 3 months. If that is correct, then you will only have 4-5 months employment according to what you have stated here. Unless I misunderstand the implications of this reason given, I believe the UK would like to see more than 3-4 months of employment from someone coming to take a PLAB 2.

The most important aspect here is to answer the reasons for the refusal directly. Establish your employment and your finances to satisfy an immigration officer of your intentions and your capability to meet the expectations of a visitor in this category.

Comment: PLABS come under Appendix V, visitor rules